# embedding tags in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xslt which is working:

```
<xsl:when test="area_of_expertise">

    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="area_of_expertise"/>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

but what i need is along the lines of:

```
<xsl:when test="area_of_expertise">

    <div id="<xsl:value-of select="area_of_expertise"/>">
        <xsl:value-of select="area_of_expertise"/>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

However the second example has errors.. does anyone know why?

Btw Is there a way we can transform the node's name `area_of_expertise` into `areaOfExperiseLabel` and insert that as the id? the output that i really need is this:

```
<div id="areaOfExpertiseLabel">
    asasdasdasd
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2nd part try using this template:

```
<xsl:template name="parse">
        <xsl:param name="input"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>


        <xsl:if test="$position &lt;= string-length($input)">

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="substring($input, $position, 1) = '_'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($input, $position + 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>

                    <xsl:call-template name="parse">
                        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 2"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise>

                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, $position, 1)"/>

                    <xsl:call-template name="parse">
                        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:if>


    </xsl:template>
```

Usage:

```
<xsl:call-template name="parse">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'area_of_expertise'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: For the love of God, please use a library instead of doing manual parsing like this. See DCharness's answer.

Comment: @Jordan heys i couldn't get dcharness's answer to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289509/xslt-string-functions-not-working-as-expected can you help me with it thx

Comment: @Pacerier you really should've opened another question. You accepted an answer that has nothing to do with the original question you asked.

Comment: @Pacerier, yeah I understand that, but you edited your original question to include that 2nd part, and it should generally be a separate question rather than adding something on, or the answers become quite entangled.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it errors out is because it's no longer valid XML.

To do what you're trying to do:

```
<xsl:when test="title">

    <div id="{title}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

You can put any sort of selector inside of the {} tags, or even reference variables if you have something complex.

```
<xsl:variable name="some_complex_variable">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:when test="title">

    <div id="{$some_complex_variable}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

A 3rd, long-winded way of doing it is to dynamically attach the attribute with xsl:attribute:

```
<xsl:when test="title">

    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="title"/>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: heys thx for the help.. btw i've updated the question, could you help me with the second part?

Comment: name().) or local-name(.) should get you the name of the node anywhere that you want it. <div id="{name(.)"> would work if you're in a loop, for example. The "." is just a selector. You can replace that with any XPath.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, converting from underscores to camel case, you may want to look at   [String Processing in the XSLT Standard Library](http://xsltsl.sourceforge.net/string.html). With `str:subst()` to split at underscores, `str:to-camelcase()` to change letter case suitably, and `concat()` to add the "Label" suffix, you should be set.

Comment: heys could you help me with this. in that page is writes str:substr() `disable-output-escaping: A value of yes indicates that the result should have output escaping disabled. Any other value allows normal escaping of text values. The default is to enable output escaping.` but i'd still not understand what is it saying..

Comment: heys i couldn't get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289509/xslt-string-functions-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Normally, XSLT output escapes characters special to XML, "& and < (and possibly other characters)", in text node output.  This parameter lets you avoid that, if for example, you're generating non-XML output from the XML input.  Since you're looking for XML output, you can leave this at the default of no.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st part you could use:

```
<xsl:when test="area_of_expertise">
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="area_of_expertise"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:value-of select="area_of_expertise"/>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a silly answer, but it seems that you need this simple trace:

```
<xsl:when test="area_of_expertise">
    <div id="areaOfExperiseLabel">
        <xsl:value-of select="area_of_expertise"/>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

Otherwise, why are you intersted in `<xsl:value-of select="area_of_expertise"/>` for `@id` if you then need another string?

Comment: i don't want to type `areaOfExperiseLabel` myself, i want to have a way for the computer to derive that from `area_of_expertise`

Comment: However, your requ. makes sense if you don't know the element name _a priori_. Is it your case then? And in that case, how can you match it?

Comment: well i need a function to do that because `area_of_expertise` is not the only "string" that needs this kind of transformation, there's like 10 others that require this cameling-transformation

Comment: ok, so what's no good in the other answers? and you search for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: @empo i can't get dcharness's answer to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289509/xslt-string-functions-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @emp i would like a 2.0 solution

Comment: You already have accpeted the answer. So, it is assumed you are ok with that.

Comment: yes its working.. despite that being an ugly solution so of course if there's a better way i'll be searching for it then..