# translate a pattern in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i am using XSLT 1.0 version and got stuck in translating a pattern. I need to translate string `'nn'` with `'XZ'`. Translate function is not working for me. Please suggest how this can be achieved in XSLT 1.0 version without writing seprate template for it in one liner.

Comment: Can you share the expressions that you were trying ?
Ideally it should work for 1.0.

Comment: Please describe the way you are applying your transform. Are you using an XSLT compliant processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using recursive template: [embedding tags in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274652/embedding-tags-in-xslt/6277311#6277311)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string-before()` and `string-after()` to achieve your goal:

```
<xsl:variable name="prefix" select="substring-before($value, 'nn')" />
<xsl:variable name="suffix" select="substring-after($value, 'nn')" />

<xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, 'XZ', $suffix)" />
```

Comment: but this 'nn' can come into multiple places. It seems i have to write a template to achieve this.