# How can we use EXSLT without downloading its source?

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

[XSLTSL](http://xsltsl.sourceforge.net/#id1954375) seems to claim that we can use EXSLT without downloading its source:

> Import or include either the main stylesheet, or the stylesheet module you wish to use, directly from the library website; http://xsltsl.sourceforge.net/modules/. The modules directory always contains the latest stable release.

I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="http://xsltsl.sourceforge.net/modules/string.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="str:to-upper">
      <xsl:with-param name="text">hello world</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But its not working. I don't seem to be able to use EXSLT without downloading its source.

Is there anyway to use EXSLT without downloading its source?

Comment: Others have answered your question, but note if you can use XSLT 2.0 then <xsl:value-of select="upper-case('f')"/> does the trick.

Comment: @alexbrn heys i've edited the question could you help me with it thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the library correctly. Take a look at the instructions [here](http://xsltsl.sourceforge.net/#id1954375).

Once you have downloaded the library, you need to:

1) Add an import to your xsl file:

```
<xsl:import href="string.xsl"/>
```

2) Add a namespace:

```
xmlns:str="http://xsltsl.org/string"
```

3) Call the template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:call-template name="str:to-upper">
    <xsl:with-param name="text">hello world</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

This will produce `HELLO WORLD`.

**UPDATE:**

No, you do not need to download the library locally. You can simply link to `string.xsl` using the full URL.

Comment: heys i'd still can't get it to work. btw i've edited the question take a look at it

Comment: you still haven't added a namespace. Change to: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:str="http://xsltsl.org/string"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Comment: and, no, it is not necessary to download a local copy of the xslt.

Comment: Some XSLT processors can only handle local URLs, so downloading may be necessary, if @Pacerier is using such a processor.

Answer (score 2):

As is explaind in [Using the library](http://xsltsl.sourceforge.net/#id1954375), you need to download it and

```
<xsl:import href="stdlib.xsl"/>
```

import it into your xslt script.

Btw, as an alternative you can also use the xslt translate function:

```
translate(value,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","ABCBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

It is a bit big to use in multiple places, but as long as you can place this in a template that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: heys i'd still can't get it to work. btw i've edited the question take a look at it

Comment: @Pacerier, looks like you forgot to declare the namespace using `xmlns:str="http://xsltsl.org/string"` in the `<xsl:stylesheet` tag.